# npm install failing with node-pre-grp and node-grp

Tags: react-native, npm, grpc, node-gyp

**Problem:** 
whenever I run npm install firebase or realm --save I get this error :

[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffxXz.png)

[more log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Sixk.png)

then, after this, when I try to run the project with react-native run-android I get this  :

[when I run react-native run-android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cr9Zt.png)

I've tried reinstalling the node modules with npm install, I've cleared my npm cache, I've tried installing firebase globally then using npm link firebase, then react-native link firebase, I've tried disabling my antivirus, even updating the grnc build, and even installed the .NET Framework. I've tried following every different tutorial I could find on linking firebase with react-native, and of the 20 things I've tried, nothing has worked.... Thanks

I've now also tried creating a project in a linux vm, and I got the same error when I tried to install realm and firebase. I've also wiped my entire computer to get a fresh install of everything from node to python to MSBuild tools..

I finally found that react-native install firebase and react-native install realm end up working in cmd, but the packages aren't actually added to the project, even though cmd says downloaded and linked

Comment: If you're seeing errors, please copy the relevant text into the question instead of linking elsewhere.

Comment: I tried but it seems it won't fit the screen very well, and it won't be colored like it is in the console, I'm also not really sure what's relevant, sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a weird workaround that solves the problem for a specific project but won't solve the entire problem.

1. create a github repository and upload the project, make sure to get rid of gitignore as well so that all the node modules are also uploaded.
2. get another computer to clone the repo and install firebase/realm
3. clone the project, cd into /android and run the command 'gradlew clean'
4. should be good to go!

Alternate Route:

1. create a Virtual machine with Virtualbox and get Ubuntu running
2. add a shared folder between the host and VM
3. move your react native project into the shared folder
4. cd into the shared folder in your VM
5. run react-native install {Youre package here) on the project
6. Should be good to go!